# Error while downloading file from jasper

Tags: nullpointerexception, jasper-reports, bigdata, jasperserver

I am trying to download report from oracle 11g using jasper server. The URL is calling from APEX. For small files its working correctly

But when the report become 15MB or something the exported file is showing error. It is not apex time out. The output file format is excel and it is getting exported but there is no data. I used virtualization and changed the memory size mentioned in config file..it didnt helped..

its showing error as below

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ReportParametersAction.getInputControlWrappers(ReportParametersAction.java:297)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ReportParametersAction.hasInputs(ReportParametersAction.java:302)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ViewReportAction.saveInputsState(ViewReportAction.java:396)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ViewReportAction.runReport(ViewReportAction.java:332)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.DispatchMethodInvoker.invoke(DispatchMethodInvoker.java:98)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.MultiAction.doExecute(MultiAction.java:123)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:79)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:391)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:386)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:535) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:364)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:222)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor292.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>   at $Proxy19.launchExecution(Unknown Source) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.IPadSupportFilter.doFilter(IPadSupportFilter.java:67)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.java:154)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:139)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:184)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:184)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSCsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(JSCsrfGuardFilter.java:81)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.WebAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebAppSecurityFilter.java:83)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.MultipartRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(MultipartRequestWrapperFilter.java:90)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: Pls somebody help on this...